# phppgadmin no carga la base de datos de pgadmin

Tags: php, postgresql, web, webservice, pgadmin

Tengo un problema a la que no que no sé si alguien tenga respuesta alguna ante la nula información que hay de phppgadmin en 2023 y si hay expertos en la materia. Intenté integrar en XAMPP a phppgadmin pero me dejaba el mensaje de "Error al cargar servers.php", o sea que ni siquiera me dio chance de loguearme con usuario y contraseña, la vista de usuario y contraseña la encontré más adelante pero no me dejó loguearme, siempre me presentaba esta lista de errores que muestro a continuación:

Deprecated: Creation of dynamic property FieldDecorator::$f is deprecated in C:\xampp\php\phppgadmin\libraries\decorator.inc.php on line 106

Deprecated: Creation of dynamic property FieldDecorator::$f is deprecated in C:\xampp\php\phppgadmin\libraries\decorator.inc.php on line 106

Deprecated: Creation of dynamic property UrlDecorator::$b is deprecated in C:\xampp\php\phppgadmin\libraries\decorator.inc.php on line 177

Deprecated: Creation of dynamic property UrlDecorator::$q is deprecated in C:\xampp\php\phppgadmin\libraries\decorator.inc.php on line 179

Deprecated: Creation of dynamic property FieldDecorator::$f is deprecated in C:\xampp\php\phppgadmin\libraries\decorator.inc.php on line 106

Deprecated: Creation of dynamic property FieldDecorator::$f is deprecated in C:\xampp\php\phppgadmin\libraries\decorator.inc.php on line 106

Deprecated: Creation of dynamic property FieldDecorator::$f is deprecated in C:\xampp\php\phppgadmin\libraries\decorator.inc.php on line 106

Deprecated: Creation of dynamic property FieldDecorator::$f is deprecated in C:\xampp\php\phppgadmin\libraries\decorator.inc.php on line 106

Deprecated: Creation of dynamic property FieldDecorator::$f is deprecated in C:\xampp\php\phppgadmin\libraries\decorator.inc.php on line 106

Les dejo los códigos por default que me dejó el source de phppgadmin para saber de casualidad que es lo que le tengo que cambiar, que opinan al respecto o si es lo que estoy sospechando. Lo que pasa es que mi postgresql es versión 15 y phppgadmin al aprecer hace rato que no se actualiza para nuevas versiones y la aparentemente última versión que es la 7.3 de phppgadmin se almacenó en la nube de github, para que se den una idea de la situación, saludos:

Este es el código de servers.php (El que no carga en phppgadmin)

```
/**
     * Manage servers
     *
     * $Id: servers.php,v 1.12 2008/02/18 22:20:26 ioguix Exp $
     */

    // Include application functions
    $_no_db_connection = true;
    include_once('./libraries/lib.inc.php');
    
    $action = (isset($_REQUEST['action'])) ? $_REQUEST['action'] : '';
    if (!isset($msg)) $msg = '';
    
    function doLogout() {
        global $misc, $lang, $_reload_browser, $plugin_manager;

        $plugin_manager->do_hook('logout', $_REQUEST['logoutServer']);

        $server_info = $misc->getServerInfo($_REQUEST['logoutServer']);
        $misc->setServerInfo(null, null, $_REQUEST['logoutServer']);

        unset($_SESSION['sharedUsername'], $_SESSION['sharedPassword']);

        doDefault(sprintf($lang['strlogoutmsg'], $server_info['desc']));

        $_reload_browser = true;
    }

    function doDefault($msg = '') {
        global $conf, $misc;
        global $lang;
        
        $misc->printTabs('root','servers');
        $misc->printMsg($msg);
        $group = isset($_GET['group']) ? $_GET['group'] : false;
        
        $groups = $misc->getServersGroups(true,$group);

        $columns = array(
            'group' => array(
                'title' => $lang['strgroup'],
                'field' => field('desc'),
                'url' => 'servers.php?',
                'vars' => array('group' => 'id'),
            ),
        );
        $actions = array();

        if (($group !== false) and (isset($conf['srv_groups'][$group])) and ($groups->recordCount()>0)) {
            $misc->printTitle(sprintf($lang['strgroupgroups'],htmlentities($conf['srv_groups'][$group]['desc'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')));
        }

        $misc->printTable($groups, $columns, $actions,'servers-servers');

        $servers = $misc->getServers(true, $group);
        
        function svPre(&$rowdata, $actions) {
            $actions['logout']['disable'] = empty($rowdata->fields['username']);
            return $actions;
        }
        
        $columns = array(
            'server' => array(
                'title' => $lang['strserver'],
                'field' => field('desc'),
                'url'   => "redirect.php?subject=server&amp;",
                'vars'  => array('server' => 'id'),
            ),
            'host' => array(
                'title' => $lang['strhost'],
                'field' => field('host'),
            ),
            'port' => array(
                'title' => $lang['strport'],
                'field' => field('port'),
            ),
            'username' => array(
                'title' => $lang['strusername'],
                'field' => field('username'),
            ),
            'actions' => array(
                'title' => $lang['stractions'],
            ),
        );
        
        $actions = array(
            'logout' => array(
                'content' => $lang['strlogout'],
                'attr'=> array (
                    'href' => array (
                        'url' => 'servers.php',
                        'urlvars' => array (
                            'action' => 'logout',
                            'logoutServer' => field('id')
                        )
                    )
                )
            ),
        );

        if (($group !== false) and isset($conf['srv_groups'][$group])) {
            $misc->printTitle(sprintf($lang['strgroupservers'],htmlentities($conf['srv_groups'][$group]['desc'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')));
            $actions['logout']['attr']['href']['urlvars']['group'] = $group;
        }

        $misc->printTable($servers, $columns, $actions, 'servers-servers', $lang['strnoobjects'], 'svPre');
    }
    
    function doTree() {
        global $misc, $conf;

        $nodes = array();
        $group_id = isset($_GET['group']) ? $_GET['group'] : false;

        /* root with srv_groups */
        if (isset($conf['srv_groups']) and count($conf['srv_groups']) > 0
            and $group_id === false)
        {
            $nodes = $misc->getServersGroups(true);
        }
        /* group subtree */
        else if (isset($conf['srv_groups']) and $group_id !== false) {
            if ($group_id !== 'all')
                $nodes = $misc->getServersGroups(false, $group_id);
            $nodes = array_merge($nodes, $misc->getServers(false, $group_id));
            include_once('./classes/ArrayRecordSet.php');
            $nodes = new ArrayRecordSet($nodes);
        }
        /* no srv_group */
        else {
            $nodes = $misc->getServers(true, false);
        }
        
        $reqvars = $misc->getRequestVars('server');
        
        $attrs = array(
            'text'   => field('desc'),
            
            // Show different icons for logged in/out
            'icon'   => field('icon'),
            
            'toolTip'=> field('id'),
            
            'action' => field('action'),

            // Only create a branch url if the user has
            // logged into the server.
            'branch' => field('branch'),
        );
        
        $misc->printTree($nodes, $attrs, 'servers');
        exit;
    }


    if ($action == 'tree')
        doTree();

    $misc->printHeader($lang['strservers']);
    $misc->printBody();
    $misc->printTrail('root');

    switch ($action) {
        case 'logout':
            doLogout();
            break;
        default:
            doDefault($msg);
            break;
    }

    $misc->printFooter();
?>
```

Y este es el de decorator.inc.php, donde se está presentando el error de Deprecated

```
<?php
// $Id: decorator.inc.php,v 1.8 2007/04/05 11:09:38 mr-russ Exp $

// This group of functions and classes provides support for
// resolving values in a lazy manner (ie, as and when required)
// using the Decorator pattern.

###TODO: Better documentation!!!

// Construction functions:

function field($fieldName, $default = null) {
    return new FieldDecorator($fieldName, $default);
}

function merge(/* ... */) {
    return new ArrayMergeDecorator(func_get_args());
}

function concat(/* ... */) {
    return new ConcatDecorator(func_get_args());
}

function callback($callback, $params = null) {
    return new CallbackDecorator($callback, $params);
}

function ifempty($value, $empty, $full = null) {
    return new IfEmptyDecorator($value, $empty, $full);
}

function url($base, $vars = null /* ... */) {
    // If more than one array of vars is given,
    // use an ArrayMergeDecorator to have them merged
    // at value evaluation time.
    if (func_num_args() > 2) {
        $v = func_get_args();
        array_shift($v);
        return new UrlDecorator($base, new ArrayMergeDecorator($v));
    }
    return new UrlDecorator($base, $vars);
}

function replace($str, $params) {
    return new replaceDecorator($str, $params);
}

// Resolving functions:

function value(&$var, &$fields, $esc = null) {
    if (is_a($var, 'Decorator')) {
        $val = $var->value($fields);
    } else {
        $val =& $var;
    }

    if (is_string($val)) {
        switch($esc) {
            case 'xml':
                return strtr($val, array(
                    '&' => '&amp;',
                    "'" => '&apos;', '"' => '&quot;',
                    '<' => '&lt;', '>' => '&gt;'
                ));
            case 'html':
                return htmlentities($val, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
            case 'url':
                return urlencode($val);
        }
    }
    return $val;
}

function value_xml(&$var, &$fields) {
    return value($var, $fields, 'xml');
}

function value_xml_attr($attr, &$var, &$fields) {
    $val = value($var, $fields, 'xml');
    if (!empty($val))
        return " {$attr}=\"{$val}\"";
    else
        return '';
}

function value_url(&$var, &$fields) {
    return value($var, $fields, 'url');
}

// Underlying classes:

class Decorator
{
    function __construct($value) {
        $this->v = $value;
    }
    
    function value($fields) {
        return $this->v;
    }
}

class FieldDecorator extends Decorator
{
    function __construct($fieldName, $default = null) {
        $this->f = $fieldName;
        if ($default !== null) $this->d = $default;
    }
    
    function value($fields) {
        return isset($fields[$this->f]) ? value($fields[$this->f], $fields) : (isset($this->d) ? $this->d : null);
    }
}

class ArrayMergeDecorator extends Decorator
{
    function __construct($arrays) {
        $this->m = $arrays;
    }
    
    function value($fields) {
        $accum = array();
        foreach($this->m as $var) {
            $accum = array_merge($accum, value($var, $fields));
        }
        return $accum;
    }
}

class ConcatDecorator extends Decorator
{
    function __construct($values) {
        $this->c = $values;
    }
    
    function value($fields) {
        $accum = '';
        foreach($this->c as $var) {
            $accum .= value($var, $fields);
        }
        return trim($accum);
    }
}

class CallbackDecorator extends Decorator
{
    function __construct($callback, $param = null) {
        $this->fn = $callback;
        $this->p = $param;
    }
    
    function value($fields) {
        return call_user_func($this->fn, $fields, $this->p);
    }
}

class IfEmptyDecorator extends Decorator
{
    function __construct($value, $empty, $full = null) {
        $this->v = $value;
        $this->e = $empty;
        if ($full !== null) $this->f = $full;
    }
    
    function value($fields) {
        $val = value($this->v, $fields);
        if (empty($val))
            return value($this->e, $fields);
        else
            return isset($this->f) ? value($this->f, $fields) : $val;
    }
}

class UrlDecorator extends Decorator
{
    function __construct($base, $queryVars = null) {
        $this->b = $base;
        if ($queryVars !== null)
            $this->q = $queryVars;
    }
    
    function value($fields) {
        $url = value($this->b, $fields);
        
        if ($url === false) return '';
        
        if (!empty($this->q)) {
            $queryVars = value($this->q, $fields);
            
            $sep = '?';
            foreach ($queryVars as $var => $value) {
                $url .= $sep . value_url($var, $fields) . '=' . value_url($value, $fields);
                $sep = '&';
            }
        }
        return $url;
    }
}

class replaceDecorator extends Decorator
{
    function __construct($str, $params) {
        $this->s = $str;
        $this->p = $params;
    }

    function value($fields) {
        $str = $this->s;
        foreach ($this->p as $k => $v) {
            $str = str_replace($k, value($v, $fields), $str);
        }
        return $str;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A partir de PHP 8.2, la creación dinámica de propiedades es obsoleta; seguramente estás utilizando esa versión de PHP o una superior. En todo caso, los mensajes que indicas no son errores, sino *warnings*.

La explicación un poco más técnica se encuentra al observar el código de la clase `Decorator` y cualquiera de las que señalas en tu pregunta (`FieldDecorator`, por ejemplo).

Nota que en sus constructores hay asignaciones del tipo `$this->variable = $valor` (por ejemplo, en el constructor de `Decorator` está la asignación `$this->v = $value;`), **pero**, y aquí está la clave, la clase no contiene una definición de la variable (`v` en el ejemplo que cité).

**¿Cómo solventarlo?**

No sé si a la fecha hay una versión de **phpPgAdmin** con el cambio de código necesario, si la hay, la solución recomendada sería actualizar **phpPgAdmin**. Si no, entonces basta con usar la anotación `#[AllowDynamicProperties]` en la definición de [la superclase] `Decorator` (para que sea heredada por sus subclases y así no tener que repetir código) de la siguiente forma:

```
#[AllowDynamicProperties]
class Decorator
{
    function __construct($value) {
        $this->v = $value;
    }
    
    function value($fields) {
        return $this->v;
    }
}
```

Espero que esto aclare tu duda y te ayude a solucionar.

Saludos.